# Plesk API Documentation

Tags: untagged

Does anyone know where to find full Plesk API documentation?  I can find how to send a request but I don't know what types of requests I can send nor the variables to send along with them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find everthing you need in the [Parallels Technology Network](http://www.parallels.com/ptn/documentation/plesk/).